# Update PrimeFaces fileupload template

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I'm currently working with PrimeFaces fileupload and need to update the upload template (the JavaScript part).
I have been trying different ways to update the template without redefine the widget like:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.FileUpload = PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend({...});
```

Is there a more easy or common way? Like using the widgetVar? Eg:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    fileuploadwidget.cfg.uploadTemplate = '...';
});
```

I have had no luck with that thougt..

Comment: do you mean messageTemplate ?

Comment: No, sorry I ment the the uploadTemplate that holds the table row.
Like in this.cfg.uploadTemplate

Comment: post your full code of the template please...

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I ended up with writing an external JS file that loads when the DOM is loaded and added different events to the input. To change the layout I use CSS display: none to hide the parts I dont want. I did fint this the fastest and easiest way

Comment: You can post it as an answer, might help some searchers